# Close Button disappeared in Debian

Tags: java, swing, jframe, debian

[image]I have a Jframe that compiles and runs correctly in Windows but when I try to run it in Debian there is no close buttons or title bar.

I am using the default look and feel so what am I missing to get this to work?

Comment: Debian is not Debian. Which Windowmanager is in use? Gnome? Try to go with the mouse to the top of your screen ...

Comment: I am using LXDE-pi. The application opens at the very top of my screen.  There is no frame decoration at all.

Comment: Would you mind posting a screenshot?

Comment: Ok, I added a photo,  I couldn't find a way to screenshot in LXDe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by

```
setType(Type.POPUP);
```

I changed to the below to fix it.

```
 setType(Type.NORMAL);
```